Bathroom exhaust vent flow measurement
I'm remodeling a first floor bathroom and changing out the traditional fan with an inline Fantech FG4XLEC that I'm putting in the 2nd floor attic. There's an existing vertical chase I'm reusing. I've installed 10' of 4" rigid duct (two 5' sections) in the chase and about 5' of insulated aluminized flex in the bathroom ceiling to make a turn and connect to a 6 x 10 register box in the ceiling. In the 2nd floor attic I've got a little bit more flex, maybe 3' total, to make it easier to connect between the rigid duct, the inline fan and the roof vent. The FG4XLEC is rated to 160 CFM, which should be well above what I need for a 5'd x 10'w x 8.5'h bathroom and has a speed control, which I've dialed back to ~50%.
Before I put drywall up on the ceiling, what's the best way to test that I have adequate flow? I bought a cheap anemometer from Amazon and at the 4" duct opening of the register box, I've measured about 62 CFM (some loss was expected, right?). I get significantly less CFM at the 6x10 opening but I've been told those cheap anemometer don't measure low speeds very well.  I could turn the fan speed back up but I'm trying to keep the noise level down too. I supposed I could use a cardboard box to cover the 6x10 opening and cut a hole in it the same size as the anemometer but wouldn't that be the same as measuring right at the duct opening inside the register box?
I stuck an 8.5x11 piece of stiff paperboard up to the register opening and it stuck there pretty hard. I know that doesn't tell me if the flow is adequate but it does tell me it's working.
Thanks for any suggestions.

take a piece of toilet paper and see if it sticks

The rule of thumb is 1CFM per sq ft of floor space, so your bath should have good air circulation even if the 62CFM is accurate.

Yup. I understand the requirements. I'm trying to ensure I meet them.
